# how to get path to webpage in WAR in netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish

I have the following myXML.xml file which I need to get the relative path to.
The directory is

```
myProjectName-WAR 

Web-Pages 

WEB-INF , +searches

-searches > myXML.xml
```

The absolute path is

```
C:\Users\myUser\Documents\NetBeansProjects\myProjectName\myProjectName-war\web\searches\myXML.xml
```

I need something that can give me a path that will work if the project is exported as a jar, like System.getProperty("user.dir") --- but user.dir gives me

```
C:\Users\myUser\Documents\NetBeansProjects\myProjectName\GlassFish_Server\glassfish\domains\domain1\config
```

I've googled and a possible solution includes

```
ServletContext context = getContext();
String fullPath = context.getRealPath("/searches/myXML.xml");
```

but getContext() can't be found, so I'm at a loss right now.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
request.getContextPath()
```